# Error in Play Store: Insufficient storage available

Tags: google-play-store, insufficient-memory

I'm using a Moto E. A while ago, my phone decided to show me the following message when downloading apps, despite me having around 300 Mb more than was required:

> Error while downloading (Insert app name), Insufficient storage available

After some thorough internet research, I found that the best way to solve the issue was to install the [App Cache Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache&hl=en). This worked, and I was able to install apps once more.

However, after a while, the message started appearing again, except this time, it was just:

> Error. Insufficient storage available.

I researched this issue, and found that the only possible way to solve it was to clear the data from the Google Play app. This just made things worse, as it has gotten rid of the Google Play Services app, and I cannot do anything without reinstalling, and updating it, which I can obviously not do.

How do I solve this issue?

Edit: I have tried clearing all caches, clearing the Google play data, disabling and re-enabling Google play, deleting apps, and restarting my phone as suggested, all of which have not worked.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Culprit here is to decide *where* the space is missing. I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please follow up to [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info): as that's a quite frequent question here, we've compiled some first-aid there. Check if that helps you, then come back here to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17845/192154) if solved or [edit] it and let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

this is   what i learned from my old 1gb app storage phone. To stop notification of insufficiant storage.

1. clear cache found in setting>storage>internal memory cache.
2. your phone needed some least amount of memory to work(hide notification) which was 150~200mb for me.Try to maintain the storage of 250mb reserved.
3. deleting google play not works.Deleting play service may give you some memory but you will need play service.

   if still getting the notification at app install just remove your gmail account and untinstall play store (not play service) to factory version then reinstall/update play store and add account.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I received from Irulu...

### Your settings setup may differ from the setup of Irulu - but the process is the same: Don't delete Google play store or Google play services - just CLEAR DATA.

Sorry for this,we confirmed this problem with our workmate and here is the solution for reference:

1. Go to settings
2. Scroll down on the left side of the screen.
3. Select apps
4. On the right side of the screen, scroll to the left until you cannot scroll any further. You will see the word "ALL" in the top middle of the screen.
5. Scroll down on the right side of the screen.
6. Select "Google Services Framework"
7. Scroll halfway down the page and select "Clear Data" then "ok"
8. Press the back arrow button one time.
9. Select "Google play store"
10. Select "Clear Data" then "OK".